# How to estimate distribution from DataBase?

Tags: density-function, data-mining, mutual-information

I am currently working on a programme to compute the mutual information between a variable and a set of variables. Since I am working with discrete data, I am computing $\sum_{a\in A,b\in B,c\in C}P(A=a,B=b,C=c)\times\log_{2}\left({P(C=c)P(A=a,B=b,C=c)\over P(A=a,C=c)\times P(B=b,C=c)}\right)$ where I look up in my DataBase, how often there is an event "A=a,B=b,C=c" and so on. From these counts I want to approximate the probability of these events.

My supervisor asked me, if I really believe my approximation to be reasonable, since my DataBase is approximately 40000 entries long, each variable has 200 discrete values, and I use conditional independence tests with up to 6 variables in the conditional set.

My argument is, that I estimate the distribution Maximum Likelihood-style, but on the other hand, I have to admit that I have too few data to back up my Maximum Likelihood estimation.

So: what would you do? Stick to the Maximum Likelihood estimation? In WEKA, for example, they also do this. However: can you give me any hints what I should do?

Comment: To what "approximation" do you refer?  It is difficult to determine what you are doing or what you are really asking.

Comment: I asked how I shall approximate $P(a,b,c)$. I can do this by counting how many events where $A=a,B=b,C=c$ are in my DataBase, or I could try to fit a distribution to get this information. Up until now, I am just counting the events.

Comment: It is hard to tell what your notation means. It seems you might be confounding the distinction between some true underlying value (a probability?) and data-based estimates of it.  If you would edit your question to provide a description of what expressions like "$P(a,b,c)$" and "$P(a,c)$" etc. mean then it might become clear enough to answer.